# How to change alignment of combobox's dropdown button?

Tags: css, combobox

By default, combobox's dropdown button is on the right.
I need to place it right in the center. How do I do that?
Is there any possibility to change it's x-coordinate position along the widget?

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a trick of showing an image instead of the arrow, with `background-position-x` positioning it where ever you want, left, right or even middle:

```css
    select{
        width: 268px;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 1;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 5px;
        height: 34px;
        padding-left:40px;
        background: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png) no-repeat right #ddd;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        background-position-x: 14px; // use this to scale
    }
```

```html
<select>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>           
</select>
```